# Sudo command takes time to run after Sierra

Tags: terminal, command-line, sudo

A few days back I updated my iMac from El Capitan to Sierra. I have then noticed that the sudo command is not working properly. When I use something like `sudo -v` or `sudo npm install grunt -g` it becomes stuck and doesn't ask for the password immediately, as it takes like 20–30 mins and then shows the password prompt.

I am not sure is it because of the Sierra update or something else, but this is really annoying me, as I can't install npm packages and other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of reading and all, I found that AMPPS entry in sudoers file is culprit.

open sudoers file using `sudo visudo` command OR use some editor (take backup of sudoers file before making changes and also read guide to use "visodo" )

I commented 2 lines in my sudoers file and everything is fine now.

```
#%amit ALL= NOPASSWD: /Applications/AMPPS/Ampps.app
#%amit ALL= NOPASSWD: /Applications/AMPPS/ampps
```

Similar experience/solution has been shared by this blogger [here](https://macperformanceguide.com/blog/2017/20170407_1157-macOS-10_12_4-sudo-broken-fix.html),

You might not be having AMPPS on your machine so what worked for me, might not work for you.

Point to highlight is **"There is something in there in your sudoers file which is causing issue, just find that line"**